# Unprotect fails the first time, works on second pass

Tags: function-construction, kernel

I am redefining some of the standard math functions. I know this is dangerous, so I am trying to be extra careful. (For instance, in the redefinitions, I make sure to only match a custom head)

The redefinitions generally went smoothly. However, I noticed that the following code bit produces an error, but only when you run it the first time (using a "fresh" Kernel):

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[p_customHead, q_Quantity] := p + q
Protect[Plus];
-> SetDelayed::write: "Tag Plus in p_customHead+q_Quantity is Protected. "
```

If you run the snippet a second time, it works, and the subsequent code behaves as expected (my actual redefinition is a bit more complicated and produces results that are different from a simple `p+q`).

I already feel uneasy about redefining the standard math functions, and this behaviour makes me doubt if I should venture any further in this direction. Is this sort of thing to be expected when using `Unprotect`?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate - I saw the StackOverflow question/answer too late.

Comment: Related: [(18468)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18468/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [an answer on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649618/2421916) StackOverflow, which I cannot reduce any further, so I'll quote:

> As you might well know, Mathematica loads binary MX files that
>   implement some of its functionality. These MX files store
>   implementations as well as definitions and attributes.
>
> This is insidious, but your Unprotect[Rule] is undone by Mathematica's
>   newly loaded MX file, and this explains why it worked the second time.
>   Because Mathematica had already loaded all MX files it needed.
>
> If you first evaluate all the symbols in your expression, then it
>   stops complaining:

I modified my code accordingly, and now it works:

```
Quantity;
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[p_customHead, q_Quantity] := p + q
Protect[Plus];
```

**Addendum** As foreshadowed by Leonid's comment (see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues) and the section "*DownValues vs UpValues: System-wide changes vs. locality*" in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/14168)), I ran into weird problems when I tried to evaluate deeply nested expressions. After switching to `UpValues`, these problems went away.

The code changes were surprisingly minimal: I only had to put `customHead /:` in front of the offending assignments. After the change, there is no need to `Unprotect` the built-in functions anymore.

With these changes, the example code from the question/answer boils down to a single line:

```
customHead /: Plus[p_customHead, q_Quantity] := p + q
```

Comment: As a general comment, I would much rather use `UpValues` on `customHead`, than add a `DownValue` to `Plus`, which is generally a pretty error-prone operation and should be avoided when possible.